# iPhone: Does it ever make sense for an object to retain its delegate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, memory-management

According to the rules of memory management in a non garbage collected world, one is not supposed to retain a the calling object in a delegate. Scenario goes like this:

I have a class that inherits from UITableViewController and contains a search bar. I run expensive search operations in a secondary thread. This is all done with an NSOperationQueue and subclasses NSOperation instances. I pass the controller as a delegate that adheres to a callback protocol into the NSOperation.

There are edge cases when the application crashes because once an item is selected from the UITableViewController, I dismiss it and thus its retain count goes to 0 and dealloc gets invoked on it. The delegate didn't get to send its message in time as the results are being passed at about the same time the dealloc happens.

Should I design this differently? Should I call retain on my controller from the delegate to ensure it exists until the NSOperation itself is dealloc'd? Will this cause a memory leak? Right now if I put a retain on the controller, the crashes goes away. I don't want to leak memory though and need to understand if there are cases where retaining the delegate makes sense.

Just to recap.

UITableViewController creates an NSOperationQueue and NSOperation that gets embedded into the queue. The UITableViewController passes itself as a delegate to NSOperation. NSOperation calls a method on UITableViewController when it's ready. If I retain the UITableViewController, I guarantee it's there, but I'm not sure if I'm leaking memory. If I only use an assign property, edge cases occur where the UITableViewController gets dealloc'd and objc_msgSend() gets called on an object that doesn't exist in memory and a crash is imminent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the general case, a delegate owns the objects it has set itself as the delegate to, or at least retains references to them directly or indirectly.  In the dealloc method, a delegate should either release all objects that it is the delegate of in such a way that prevents future callbacks, like NSTimer invalidate, or clear the delegate member of those objects that may persist.

While it is only convention that prevents retaining a delegate, it is convention based on good design.  In your case, wouldn't the results be discarded anyway since the delegate is being disposed?

You can make the delegate property of your NSOperation atomic by not setting the nonatomic flag and synthesizing the getter and setter.  Or you can use performSelectorOnMainThread before using the delegate member.

To recap, there is usually a better solution than retaining the delegate.

Comment: What benefit does setting the property to atomic in this case?

Comment: Atomicity is relevant for delegates to objects running in other threads.  I do not know off hand if NSOperations are run in a separate thread, so just covering all the bases.

Comment: drawnonward: They are. That's mainly what they're for, in fact.

Comment: atomic != thread safe.  atomic just means that the data is guaranteed to be read and written as a single whole object when multiple threads are trying to simultaneously read and write the property.   As I write  in my answer, the delegate object and the operation object must instead use a multi-threading locking mechanism to insure that the delegate object can set the operation's  delegate pointer to nil in such a way that the operation can never get a stale or invalid value of the delegate pointer, and that requires more complexity.

Answer (score 2):

I really wonder though if the "don't retain your delegate" rules still  apply specifically to multi-threaded object/delegate relationships, especially the one you're writing about.   I found my way to this question because I'm in exactly the same situation: I'm running a finite but unpredictable length asynchronous network operation (it will finish and self-terminate "sometime soon")  in an NSOperation, and using a delegate stored in the NSOperation to notify completion of the operation back to the original requestor object.

Retaining the delegate in this case makes perfect sense to me.  The operation will complete eventually, it will call the "done" method on the delegate, and then will release the delegate and self-terminate.   If the calling object would have been dealloc'd while the NSOperation was running, it just sticks around a little longer until the operation completes.

Note that marking the delegate property atomic as drawnonward suggests is in itself *not sufficient* to protect against race conditions!   Setting a property as atomic only means that a reader or writer of the property will write or read an entire whole value at a time, *nothing else*.    The following sequence would result in a crash:

(NSOperation thread): NSOperation has finished and is preparing to notify the delegate object .   The code atomically reads the value of the delegate property preparing to call its "done" method.

----> Thread switch to main

(main thread) the requesting object is dealloc'd, and in `-(void)dealloc` (atomically!) sets the NSOperation's delegate property to nil, dealloc finishes, and the object is now gone

-----> Thread switch to NSOperation thread

(NSOperation thread) calls [delegate allDone] and the program crashes (if you're lucky) because the delegate object is gone.   If you're lucky.   Maybe something else was allocated in that space in the meantime and now you have unpredictable corruption, what fun!

The key thing here is that the retain cycle is *temporary* by its very nature -- the NSOperation will complete and clean up all on it own.   It's not like a UITextField and a UIViewController holding retained references to each other that will never go away and thus leak the memory.

It seems to me that retaining the delegate in the case of an asynchronous, limited, self-terminating operation is the cleanest and most robust implementation.

EDIT:

if you absolutely must not retain the delegate because it causes memory problems, then instead the delegate object and the operation object must both use an explicit locking mechanism to synchronize access to the delegate pointer stored in the operation.   "atomic" properties do *not* provide a thread-safe protocol to marking the delegate pointer nil.

But I think this gets *really* complicated and full of race conditions.   I think at the very least that you must in the delegate object's dealloc, run a locking protocol to make sure that the operation's delegate pointer is safely set to nil so that arbitrary thread interleaving cannot under any circumstances call to a dealloc'd delegate object.

Slavish adherence to rules sometimes makes things way more complicated than they need to be.   It's best to understand what the rules are, why they are there, and so you know when it makes sense (like I believe it does in this very particular scenario) not to follow them, and what the advantages/disadvantages are of doing so.

Answer (score 1):

I approach this a little differently, and I do not retain delegates.

- If I need to lose the view, I cancel the NSOperation.  I believe that its good design that if a thread's return value has nowhere to go, then the thread should stop.
- I also have seen the edge case where the thread cannot be stopped.  In this case, I nil the unretained delegate, just to be sure, and check that the delegate is not nil before making the callback.

Holding on to an object, even temporarily, when its no longer needed, especially on the iPhone chews up memory and, in my opinion, is bad design.

As per @Bogatyr's answer, a simple check for nil before calling [delegate allDone] is much cleaner.

Comment: Remember that calling [NSOperation cancel] is simply a "hint", the receiving NSOperation must note the cancel and then stop itself.   Some NSOperations *can't* stop themselves, because they're performing work inside of another framework, like sucking down image data over a URL.  @Hiltmon: checking for nil before calling *is not thread safe and is subject to the exact race condition I described*.  You must instead use some other multi-threading synchronization technique between the operation object and the delegate object to "lock" the delegate pointer before using it, which is more complex.

Answer (score 0):

You could retain the `UITableViewController` at the beginning of the `NSOperation` and release it at its end.
Alternatively, you could set it to `nil` after it is released so the dangling call from the `NSOperation` won't crash your program.
Depending on how the `NSOperation` is executed you could also autorelease the `UITableViewController` instead of releasing it, so the `NSOperation` can still use it.

However, all these things really only cure the symptoms, not the illness. The *correct* way to do it is outlined by drawnonward.