# unsafe_retained property

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, memory-management

How can I check if an unsafe_unretained property isn't point to some garbage memory? I am not using ARC. I am implementing delegate so I have to use unsafe_unretained to avoid retain cycles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not using ARC just use assign. The stale pointer problem is a coding issue, you just need to closely maintain the delegate pointer.

Comment: The reason that this is not normally a problem is that usually the delegate owns the object that is doing the delegating e.g. a view controller has a strong (retained) reference to the table view and is the delegate of that table view.  The delegate can then set the delegator's delegate to nil before releasing it.

Comment: @JeremyP I disagree, usually a delegate is a back pointer and is not owned, rather assigned. Retaining a delegate often will create a retain cycle such that neither object is released. [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2783295/451475)